# Force Akka Stream to fuse stages together

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, akka-stream

The way akka-stream fuses stages together is not very transparent. I was wondering if there is a way:

- To see which stages are fused together
- To force some stages to be fused together

Answer (score 1):

> To see which stages are fused together

I'm not aware of any documented method for revealing fused graph stages.  It's pretty safe to assume built-in linear operators will by default be fused (unless `async` is applied).

> To force some stages to be fused together

Earlier Akka Stream version does provide some methods for manual [stage fusing](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/stream/Fusing$.html) and you could elect to disable the default auto-fusing with the following configuration setting:

```
akka.stream.materializer.auto-fusing=off
```

But the latest API (`2.5`) attempts to not only handle fusing automatically under the hood, but also [disallow manual fusing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#removal-of-the-auto-fuse-setting).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#operator-fusion) is pretty transparent about operator fusion:

> By default, Akka Streams will fuse the stream operators.

Operator fusion is the default behavior, meaning that, by default, your entire stream will run within the same actor. To change this behavior, use the `async` method to define asynchronous boundaries on the stages that you don't want to be fused.

Comment: It seems straightforward with simple example, but when you have a complicated topology of graph, with some of them being async, it's harder to figure out what runs with what. Hence my question, how do you see which stages are staged together.